# Installing VMware on 18.10: Failed to build vmmon

Tags: compiling, vmware, 18.10

Trying to build the VMware modules on Ubuntu-18.10 with linux-5.0.1-050001-generic

vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

Here's the whole output:
https://pastebin.com/d61HGWJR

```
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:42:
./include/linux/mm.h:52:29: note: previous definition of ‘totalram_pages’ was here
 static inline unsigned long totalram_pages(void)
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIFReadUptimeWork’:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1787:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_gettimeofday’; did you mean ‘do_settimeofday64’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    do_gettimeofday(&tv);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    do_settimeofday64
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIF_MapUserMem’:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3408:40: error: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, p, size)) {
                                        ^
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3408:9: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, p, size)) {
         ^~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3408:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:277: /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: Task_Switch()+0x4db: indirect call found in RETPOLINE build
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1553: _module_/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:110: vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/5.0.1-050001-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001-generic'
Makefile:189: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:190: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:191: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:192: ==========================================
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/smac.o
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/userif.c: In function ‘VNetUserIfMapPtr’:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/userif.c:145:52: error: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, (void *)uAddr, size) ||
                                                    ^
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/userif.c:145:9: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, (void *)uAddr, size) ||
         ^~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/userif.c:145:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2278: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/net.h:38,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2279: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/net.h:38,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:277: /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/net.h:38,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2278: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/net.h:38,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2279: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

make[1]: *** [Makefile:1553: _module_/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:110: vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-QBnnBd/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the patches over at [github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules).

You'll need to know if you're trying to install VMWare Workstation or Player, and which version.

You can get your VMWare version with this command:

```
$ vmware -v
```

In the example below I'm assuming VMWare Workstation 15.0.1:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
$ cd vmware-host-modules
$ git checkout workstation-15.0.1
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Had the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04. alternative install method worked for me! https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/blob/master/INSTALL